# How to create a custom login form with custom forgot password form in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, forgot-password, wordpress-login, easy-digital-downloads

I have tried so many things but I am not getting a good result.

I am using Wordpress and the easy digital download plugin to sell some digital product. Now, How can I create a custom login form with custom forgat password form.

and is it possible to create a separate login form for the customers and the administrators?

I mean, on the customer's login form if someone tries to login with administrators username and password there will be no ability to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The /wp-login.php form should do most of what you want. But if that still isn't right have a look at the article attached.

https://themetrust.com/build-custom-wordpress-login-page/